# To separate the styles from a component in mui 5 styled-components [emotion]

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components, emotion

hope everyone's doing okay, wanted to ask something regarding mui 5 styled-components (the one that uses emotion under the hood). I wanted to know If there's a proper way, a standard if you will, to separate out the styles from my component and place it in another file.

Comment: Do you mean like this https://codesandbox.io/s/styledcustomization-material-demo-forked-j04e8?file=/demo.js?

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE: this solution is *NOT* using styled components**

I know this post is sort of old, but here is a pattern that I use in my react applications for custom styles when using MUI5.

Let's say we have an **AppBar MUI component** in a custom component called **Header.tsx** that has styles applied to it via the ThemeProvider, but I also have some custom div in there that I want to use my theme styles to add a background color to...

**Header.tsx** -> the component file

```
import { useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { styles } from './Header.styles.ts'; // custom css styles function

export default function Header() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const { logoWrapStyle, headTextStyle } = styles(theme);
  
  return (
    <AppBar>
      <div style={logoWrapStyle}>
        <svg>...logo_code_here...</svg>
      </div>
      <div style={headTextStyle}>
        RED TEXT IN MY HEADER
      </div>
    </AppBar>
  )
}
```

**Header.styles.ts** -> file containing the custom styles

```
export const styles = (theme: any) => {
  logoWrapStyle: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
    color: theme.palette.primary.contrastText
  },
  headTextStyle: {
    color: 'red',
  }
}
```

Not sure if of any big drawbacks to this approach, but I really like that I can create custom "one off" styles as well as accessing the theme context that is provided by the *ThemeProvider* wrapper down near the root my React component tree.

I only de-structure the styles for convenience, this is probably not necessary, but leads to cleaner final code. This is the reason I named my styles *logoWrapStyle* and *headTextStyle* - just for clarification in the code. I quickly know that this is a style from my separate **Header.styles.ts** file.

Here's a *codesandbox* with a working example of the above approach:

https://codesandbox.io/s/mui5-separate-style-file-example-zmqdv0?file=/src/App.tsx

Hope this helps somebody that comes across it!

**Code on!**

**PS:** I gave the theme parameter passed to my styles function a type of **any**, *but if you want to use proper types*, go for it!